# Brightening or darkening images in PIL without built in functions

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL for a uni project and we have one task where we have to darken or brighten an image without using any of PIL's functions to do so. The function takes the original filename, the action ('lighten' or 'darken') and the extent (in percent - an int between 0 and 100). Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
from PIL import Image

def change_brightness(filename, action, extent):
    """
    This function either increases or decreases the brightness of an image
    by altering each pixel in each band

    """
    #load the original image into a list
    original_image = Image.open(filename, 'r')
    pixels = original_image.getdata()

    #initialise the new image
    new_image = Image.new('RGB', original_image.size)
    new_image_list = []

    brightness_multiplier = 1.0

    if action == 'lighten':
        brightness_multiplier += (extent/100)
    else:
        brightness_multiplier -= (extent/100)

    #for each pixel, append the brightened or darkened version to the new image list
    for pixel in pixels:
        new_pixel = (int(pixel[0] * brightness_multiplier),
                     int(pixel[1] * brightness_multiplier),
                     int(pixel[2] * brightness_multiplier))

        #check the new pixel values are within rgb range
        for pixel in new_pixel:
            if pixel > 255:
                pixel = 255
            elif pixel < 0:
                pixel = 0

        new_image_list.append(new_pixel)

    #save the new image
    new_image.putdata(new_image_list)
    new_image.save('colour_brightness.jpg')
```

When I run this, the new image is not modified from the original (save from some new jpg artefacts). I tried `brightness_multiplier` with an explicit value (1.1 for lighten, and 0.9 for darken) and it worked, so I have no idea why it isn't working when I have it taking the value from the `extent` argument.

If anyone could shed some light it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just figured it out! I had to change the `100` in `(extent/100)` to a float and it worked! I can't answer my own question yet so i'm putting it here

Comment: note also your ‘check within range’ loop doesn't work, as it doesn't write each channel value back to the `new_pixel` list. Consider `new_pixel= [max(min(channel, 255), 0) for channel in new_pixel]`. Probably a more effective way to ‘lighten’ would be to make the difference between the channel value and 255 smaller, rather than multiplying the channel value itself as that will saturate more quickly. Better still might be to transform to the HSL colourspace, change the Lightness value, then transform back. Bonus points for thinking about gamma.

Comment: Thanks for that, bobince! I didn't even notice that (it wasn't in their test cases). As far as changing the lighting algorithm, I'm just following what it says on the task sheet (and the example results).

Comment: Ah, OK, fine for an exercise then! Real-world lighten/darken tends to be more subtle than just multiplying each channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue of integer division in the `(extent/100)` expression. To rectify this, you can:

#### use a floating point literal

```
extent/100.0
```

Handy if a term is a literal.

#### convert either the numerator or the denominator into float

```
float(extent)/a_hundred
```

If no term is a literal.

#### make sure that `/` is floating-point division

```
from __future__ import division
```

Insert that at the beginning of your source file, like all `__future__` statements.

#### invoke python with -Qnew

```
python -Qnew
```

If using python2, otherwise

#### use python3 :)

In all cases, `//` remains integer division.

Comment: Thanks for that. As it's a uni project, we have to use python 2.5 (not 2.7 for some stupid reason). I used the floating point literal method and it worked.