# Making image brightened in python using putdata

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

This is the question:

Write a program in Python which opens the file 'pixerror.png', removes the S&P noise and will correct the brightness of the image, save the processed photo under another name. You have to look pixel for pixel and cannot use blurb functions.

My fist task is to get the image brighter.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161219/brightening-or-darkening-images-in-pil-without-built-in-functions) question code, but i cannot solve my error that I have. This error:

_

> ```
> ruisclasse.py 41      
> putdata        exceptions.SystemError: 
> new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
> ```

_

And this is my code.

_

```
from __future__ import division  #for floating number
from PIL import Image
import cv2

filename='pixerror.png'
action = 'lighten'
extent = 10


#load the original image into a list
original_image = Image.open(filename, 'r')
pixels = original_image.getdata()


#initialise the new image
new_image = Image.new('RGB', original_image.size)
new_image_list = []

brightness_multiplier = 1.1

if action == 'lighten':
    brightness_multiplier += (extent/100)
else:
    brightness_multiplier -= (extent/100)



#for each pixel, append the brightened or darkened version to the new image list
for pixel in pixels:
    new_pixel = (int(pixel[0] * brightness_multiplier),
                 int(pixel[1] * brightness_multiplier),
                 int(pixel[2] * brightness_multiplier))

    #check the new pixel values are within rgb range
    new_pixel= [max(min(channel, 255), 0) for channel in new_pixel]

    new_image_list.append(new_pixel)



#save the new image
new_image.putdata(new_image_list)
new_image.save('colour_brightness.jpg')

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_pixel= [max(min(channel, 255), 0) for channel in new_pixel]
new_image_list.append(new_pixel)
```

You're appending lists to `new_image_list`, but you should be appending tuples.

```
new_pixel= [max(min(channel, 255), 0) for channel in new_pixel]
new_image_list.append(tuple(new_pixel))
```

Comment: I'd change the definition of `new_pixel` instead: `new_pixel= tuple(max(min(channel, 255), 0) for channel in new_pixel)`.